# does asymptotic behavior guarantee the uniqueness?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

Suppose $w$ is solution of 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}w+\{u(x)+k^2\}w=0$$
with asymptotic condition
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}w(x)e^{ikx}=1$$
and $u\in L^1_1(\mathbb{R})=\{f:\int_\mathbb{R}(1+|x|)|f|dx<\infty\}$, and $k>0$

Is this solution unique?

Comment: what's $w_{xx}$?

Comment: @Akababa second order derivative

Comment: This question has already been answered at MathOverflow: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292163/does-asymptotic-behavior-guarantee-uniqueness)